# Equivalent R script for repeated measures SAS script, nested design

Tags: r, sas

I'm having trouble converting an SAS script to the corresponding R script.

The model is a repeated measures analysis of the response (`resp`) based on treatment (`trt`) with plot (`plot`) nested in the treatment.

SAS code:

```
data data_set;
input trt $ plot time resp;
datalines;
Burn    1   1   27
Burn    1   9   25
Burn    1   12  18
Burn    1   15  21
Burn    2   1   5
Burn    2   9   15
Burn    2   12  10
Burn    2   15  12
...
Unburn  1   1   57
Unburn  1   9   46
Unburn  1   12  49
Unburn  1   15  51
Unburn  2   1   43
Unburn  2   9   59
Unburn  2   12  59
Unburn  2   15  60

proc mixed data = data_set;
class trt plot time;
model resp = trt time trt*time / ddfm = kr;
repeated time / subject = trt(plot) type = vc rcorr;
run;
```

R code attempted (loading the data set from a CSV file):

```
library(nlme)

data.set <- read.csv( "data_set.csv" )
data.set$plot <- factor( data.set$plot )
data.set$time <- factor( data.set$time )

model1 <- lme( resp ~ trt + time + trt:time, data = data.set, random = ~1 | plot )
```

This works, but isn't the desired model. Other attempts I've tried have generally resulted in the error:

```
Error in getGroups.data.frame(dataMix, groups) : 
  invalid formula for groups
```

Basically I'm off in the weeds here...

Question 1: how to specify the same model in R as what is already specified in SAS?

Question 2: I want to be able to change the covariance matrix to replicate other work done in SAS. I believe I know how to do this with the correlation parameter for the lme function. But please correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is expecting some grouped data frame as input. Try `lme(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)` also gives same error. When you look at example in help page, and do `class(Orthodont)`, you see it is not a straight data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specification of the model in R would logically be:

```
model1 <- lme( resp ~ trt + time + trt:time, data = data.set, random = ~1 | trt:plot )
```

This given that plot is nested in treatment per the coding, or alternatively, there is an interaction between plot and treatment. However if specified as such, then it generates the warning mentioned:

> Error in getGroups.data.frame(dataMix, groups) :    invalid formula
>   for groups

The problem encountered has to do with the levels introduced (I think) by using such an interaction. Regardless of the exact issue, the problem can be resolved by creating a combined treatment plot predictor variable:

```
data.set$trtplot <- with( data.set, factor( paste( trt, plot, sep = "." ) ) )
```

And then performing the analysis as follows:

```
model1 <- lme( resp ~ trt + time + trt:time, data = data.set, random = ~ 1 | trtplot )
```

For completeness this could just as easily be the following, where each predictor variable is added plus the interaction:

```
model1 <- lme( resp ~ trt * time, data = data.set, random = ~ 1 | trtplot )
```

This then matches results achieved in `SAS` when a `Compound Symmetry` (CS) covariance structure is specified (although the AIC criterion is a different - not sure why). So a little different to the SAS code above where a `Variance Components` (VC) covariance structure is specified, but this is just a matter of changing the structure type in the SAS code.

As for comparing different covariance structures, this appears to be more of a challenge. The covariance structures that I would like to investigate are:

- Compound Symmetry (CS) - done
- Variance Components(VC)
- Unstructured (UN)
- Spatial Power (SP)

Any thoughts would be most welcome!